# Comparing the value with the list

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am working on my code as I am calculating with the button width and the pixel to add it together to get the value. I'm trying to comparing the value with the list when I'm calculating to see if the value is come close, higher or equal to.

Here is the code:

```
CurrentRows = [375, 441, 507, 559, 610, 669, 724, 790, 838, 844, 849, 897, 910, 949, 959, 1009, 1016, 1018, 1019, 1072, 1125, 1138, 1184, 1186, 1189, 1238, 1246, 1286, 1419, 1620, 1762, 1840, 1943]

nextprogram = int(program_id) + 1
nextprogram1 = int(nextprogram) + 1
nextprogram2 = int(nextprogram1) + 1
nextprogram3 = int(nextprogram2) + 1
program_button_1 = self.getControl(int(program_id))
program_button_2 = self.getControl(int(nextprogram))
program_button_3 = self.getControl(int(nextprogram1))
program_button_4 = self.getControl(int(nextprogram2))

width = program_button_1.getWidth()
pos_X = pos_X + width + 5

for pos_X1 in CurrentRows:
   if pos_X1 >= pos_X:
      pos_X = pos_X1
      break

program_button_2.setPosition(pos_X, pos_Y)
width = program_button_2.getWidth()
pos_X = pos_X + width + 5

for pos_X1 in CurrentRows:
    if pos_X1 >= pos_X:
       pos_X = pos_X1
       break

program_button_3.setPosition(pos_X, pos_Y)
width = program_button_3.getWidth()
pos_X = pos_X + width + 5


for pos_X1 in CurrentRows:
    if pos_X1 >= pos_X:
       pos_X = pos_X1
       break
```

When the variable `pos_X` show the value `1194` which it come close to 1184, I want to get the value of `1184` from the list. When the value show `1083`, I want to get `1073` from the list, but when the value show `1125` that matched from the list I want to get `1125` from the list.

How I could do that with my code?

Comment: Will CurrentRows always be in ascending order?

Comment: yes i think so?

Comment: Is there a reason 1194 become 1184, not 1189?  I'm trying to understand your criteria

Comment: yes there is, because 1194 is got over 1184 so when the value is 1194 the closest one is 1184.

Comment: But that's a difference of 10 instead of 5.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways you could do this--I'm only listing a few. The first is what would be my favorite way of doing it, but it's probably not the most efficient, if that's what you're worried about:

```
def highest(maximum):
    return max([row for row in CurrentRows if row <= maximum])
```

The next also utilizes `max` but should only need to do one pass over the list of rows.

```
def highest(maximum):
    return max(CurrentRows, key=lambda x: x if x <= maximum else 0)
```

If for whatever reason you don't like `max` you can always iterate the list and check for yourself.

```
def highest(maximum):
    best = 0
    for x in CurrentRows:
        if x > maximum:
            return best
        best = x
    return best
```

Comment: thank you very much, but how I can use them without the call function??

Comment: If I'm understanding your question, you can just replace `maximum` with whatever variable you want and pull the code out of the function wrapper.

Comment: No, I said how i can use the variable to call the function to get the return vaue? example: `lookup = 1200 highest(lookup)`. You haven't give me the example code i could use to call the function.